# In Apache Jmeter(2.13r1665067) how to get multiple sample result using HTTP(S) Script recorder?

Tags: jmeter

Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder not generating multiple samples in listener.

I am new to JMeter and have been following the steps outlined in `usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf`.

I am using the **Recording Controller**.
I have added **HTTP(S)** Test Script Recorder to the Work Bench and added listeners: Results Tree and Results in Table.

I can successfully start the test from HTTP(S) Script recorder and I am able to view the result in `Result Table` and `Result Tree`.

The problem occurs in the case of multiple threads accessing same sample(HTTPS Request),the result returns single sample.

1. How to get multiple instances of a same sample in View Results Tree and View Results in Table?
2. Why not multiple instances of same sample are generated?

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter 2.13, you have option to use default 'Recording' template that you can find under File menu > Templates > Recording.

Just select that to record your scenario.

Under Workbench, in HTTP(S) Test Script recorder, there is dropdown menu of grouping. Select first option in it that is "Donot group samplers".

Now if you follow the steps defined in your PDF guide, you will see the samplers being recorded under Recording Controller of your Test Plan.

As for multiple threads, Please clarify what do you mean by multiple threads? In JMeter, we define number of threads (virtual users) for script execution. If your problem is for script execution then edit your question and share more accurate info as it will not be a recording problem in that case.